# Can't run remote command stored in a variable

Tags: powershell, variables, arguments, remote-access, invoke-command

I'm trying to build a script which copies files and execute them on a specific amount of servers.
To do so, I need to run a remote command. I stored it in a variable.
I know that variables can't be used within a remote session. Except you use the `-ArgumentList` parameter. But this doesn't work for me either.

Here's the code and the error message:

```
$CMD_AgentDirectory = "New-Item -Path 'C:\FlexAgent' -ItemType Directory"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server01 -ScriptBlock {
    Invoke-Expression $CMD_AgentDirectory
} -ArgumentList $CMD_AgentDirectory
```

Error Message:

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Command' because it is null.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand
    + PSComputerName        : Server01
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which Powershell Version is running on the Host and the Destination?

Comment: Add `param($CMD_AgentDirectory)` before `Invoke-Expression`

Comment: Side note: `Invoke-Expression` is practically always [the wrong tool](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/). Just put the `New-Item` commandline directly into the scriptblock (without the double quotes) or create the scriptblock from that command string.